# How to query "delivery status = unknown" on CiviMail report

Tags: civimail

I am trying to see all the emails, where the delivery status was "unknown". I have been trying to change the URL parameter "delivery_status_value" to "unknown", but that gives a fail as a response. Which value should I use for querying? Or is there another way of filtering the recipients, which's delivery status is unknown? I would have downloaded the excel/CSV file, but that does not seem to work on our system.

The version we use is 4.6.36.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE!  The first thing to note is that if you're on 4.6.36 you really need to upgrade.  There have been numerous security fixes and functionality enhancements since then.  You will also need to upgrade your version of php.  But that's not what you asked...

I needed to investigate mails with a status of 'unknown' recently.  The standard reports did not show what I wanted but the SQL behind them is a useful starting point.

From the `Mailings > Scheduled and Sent Mailings` screen, find the mailing of interest and click on `Report`.  On the `Successful Deliveries` line, click on `Report` and then go to the `Developer` tab.  From there you can copy the SQL, modify it a bit and paste it into a SQL session. How you modify it depends on what you want to know, but you will want to remove the 'where' clause that limits it to successful mails.

Things have changed a lot since 4.6 so this may not work for you.